# Redux-Logger Equivalent for Apollo / Graphql

Tags: redux, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Is there are redux-logger type of functionality for Apollo / Graphql?  Something that console.logs changes to application state and state of the cache when changes are made?  I'm working with Expo.io and React Native, and haven't been able to get any of the normal devtools working. However, logging to the console is simple and reliable enought to work in all situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apollo 2.0 has the concept of [links](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/) for this kind of use case, there are several logging links on npm:

- [apollo-link-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-logger)
- [apollo-link-logging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-logging)

  But it should also no be so hard to write your own